# Why does spampd fail with socket connection failure on openbsd?

Tags: spamassassin, openbsd

I'm having some trouble getting spampd to work in OpenBSD. First off, if I try to specify the daemon flags in my `/etc/rc.conf.local` like so:

```
spampd_flags="--port=10025 --relayhost=127.0.0.1:10027 --tagall -aw"
```

The service does not start with those flags at startup. I have to restart the service before it will pick up those flags. I found the following article mentioning the same issue from back in 2015:

http://technoquarter.blogspot.com/2015/02/openbsd-mail-server-part-4-spamassassin.html

As a workaround, I created a `/etc/rc.d/spampd_custom` script that looks like the following:

```
#!/bin/ksh

daemon="/usr/local/sbin/spampd --port=10025 --relayhost=127.0.0.1:10027 --tagall -aw"

. /etc/rc.d/rc.subr

rc_cmd $1
```

..and I added `spampd_custom` to the `pkg_scripts` in my `/etc/rc.conf/local`. This does start up the service with the correct flags, but the service will fail when attempting to make an SMTP connection. I ran it in the foreground and see this in the output:

```
# /usr/local/sbin/spampd --port=10025 --relayhost=127.0.0.1:10027 --tagall -aw
Jul 14 04:32:24 lori spampd[40465]: Pid_file "/var/run/spampd.pid" already exists.  Overwriting!  
Jul 14 04:32:24 lori spampd[4112]: Process Backgrounded 
lori# Jul 14 04:32:24 lori spampd[4112]: 2018/07/14-04:32:24 SpamPD (type Net::Server::PreForkSimple) starting! pid(4112) 
Jul 14 04:32:24 lori spampd[4112]: Binding to TCP port 10025 on host 127.0.0.1 with IPv4 
Jul 14 04:32:24 lori spampd[4112]: Setting gid to "746 746" 
Jul 14 04:32:24 lori spampd[4112]: Setting uid to "746" 
Jul 14 04:32:39 lori spampd[93147]: WARNING!! Error in process_request eval block: /usr/local/sbin/spampd: socket connect failure: Connection refused 
WARNING!! Error in process_request eval block: /usr/local/sbin/spampd: socket connect failure: Connection refused
```

I've tried several searches for this and have found some bug reports on the Debian tracker, but can't seem to find a solution. It seems like this is a socket used by the parent spampd to communicate with its children that doesn't seem to be setup correctly.

What is wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being a bug, which I [did a full write-up on](https://penguindreams.org/blog/openbsd-spampd-and-the-startup-bug/). The spampd maintainer [created an issue](https://github.com/mpaperno/spampd/issues/19) and the OpenBSD team [pulled the changed downstream](https://marc.info/?l=openbsd-ports-cvs&m=153513820421006&w=2). This should be fixed in newer releases of OpenBSD/spampd.